# How to suppress "DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction" error in valgrind output?

Tags: valgrind

I'm quite new in using valgrind. I'm running tests for my C library. I've tryed to run it under valgrind and got some very valuable info about possible errors in my code. One thing that bothers me is beginning of every valgrind session is full of messages like this:

```
DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:22
```

IIUC it's unrelated to problems in my code and I'd like to disable them to simplify analysis of other errors. I've read valgrind help but can't find the proper command-line option.

Can you provide me some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for these DWARF3 operations have been added.  Just update to the current version of valgrind, available at http://valgrind.org.