# Is there a problem running a program using the framewave library under valgrind?

Tags: c++, multithreading, valgrind

I have a set of unit tests, which are testing a program using the [framewave library](http://framewave.sourceforge.net/).

The problem occurs when I run these unit tests using valgrind to check if the code causes memory problems. It looks like the unit test enters an endless loop because it waits for some threads to be joined (although I disabled threads with `fwSetNumThreads`)

Has anyone experienced similar problems? If yes, how did you solve it?

A secondary question: do I have to pass some parameters to valgrind for multi-threaded programs?

**EDIT**

My valgrind's version is :

```
valgrind --version
valgrind-3.4.1
```

And this is what I discovered in the output that keeps on repeating (that I haven't seen before) :

```
DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
```

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520186/how-to-suppress-dwarf2-cfi-reader-unhandled-cfi-instruction-error-in-valgrind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors are actually result of a bug in valgrind (the version of valgrind I am using is 3.4.1) :

DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html
[Valgrind giving errors with getline()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086399/valgrind-giving-errors-with-getline)
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197512

Updating the valgrind to the latest version (3.6.1 at the time of writing this) fixes this error.

[How to suppress "DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction" error in valgrind output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520186/how-to-suppress-dwarf2-cfi-reader-unhandled-cfi-instruction-error-in-valgrind) explains this, but it just tells to update the valgrind to the latest version.